# Finding the roots of $x^{p}-x-1$ in a field k.

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

Let $k$ be a field containing $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ and let $\alpha$ be a root in $k$ for $x^{p}-x-1 \in \mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$
Show that the roots of $x^{p}-x-1$ in $k$ are $\alpha, \alpha-1, \cdots, \alpha-p+1$

The question gives a hint of using $f(x-\alpha)$ with $f(x)=x^{p}-x$

In $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$ we have that $x^{p}-x=x(x-1) \cdots (x-(p-1))$ so we have roots $0,1, \cdots, p-1$ but I'm not sure how to use this fact to help in the above problem. I would appreciate a hint to get me started. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the characteristic of $k$ is $p$, we have that $(\alpha - i)^p = \alpha^p - i^p = \alpha^p - i$, for any integer $i$.

Now plug $\alpha - i$ into the original polynomial $x^p - x - 1$.

Comment: Why is -i^{p}=1?

Comment: @chris Sorry, I was sloppy; it's $i$, not $1$ (which is also what you want), fixed with an edit. The reason is that anything other than zero in a finite field satisfies $x^{p-1} = 1$ (because the multiplicative group of the finite field has order $p-1$).

Comment: OK thanks. Am I right in saying that's Fermat's little theorem? i^{p-1} congruent to 1 mod p?

Comment: @Chris yes, this is Fermat's little theorem !